# How to sort a very large vector of user defined type

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I want to sort a large collection of pixels.

```
typedef char HexGetal;
typedef unsigned int NatuurlijkGetal;

struct  Pixel{
    HexGetal Blue;
    HexGetal Green;
    HexGetal Red;
};
struct Palet{   
    Pixel Kleur;
    NatuurlijkGetal Aantal; 
};
    vector <Palet> MyContainer;

    NatuurlijkGetal Seeds[10]={1, 25, 55, 7, 3, 149, 6, 7, 1, 55};


    Palet LoopPalet;


    LoopPalet.Kleur.Blue = 0;
    LoopPalet.Kleur.Green = 0;
    LoopPalet.Kleur.Red = 0;


    for(NatuurlijkGetal Looper = 0; Looper < 10;Looper++)
    {
        LoopPalet.Aantal = Seeds[Looper];
        MyContainer.push_back(LoopPalet);
    }
```

After creation of the type "Palet", i create a vector  of Palet's called "MyContainer", and initialize it.

Now i want to sort it, based on the field "Aantal".
How do i do that? I am probably looking for 2 different ways.

PART 1:
I want to learn the general way to do this when the vector is small. I have never sorted a vector. Read a lot about it and watched video's, but i'm just not getting it.

PART 2:
This vector is going to have more than 1 million elements later when used. so maybe a smarter approach is needed, to limit the amount of copy operations.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Try `std::sort` with a custom comparator. if it's measured to be too slow, look into something else.

Comment: i tried std::sort before posting, but could not get it to work, since i don't know how the custom comparator in this case could look like. As i said never done such thing before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct mycomp
{
     bool operator() (const Palet& p1, const Palet& p2)
    {
        return (p1.Aantal < p2.Aantal); //Change the operator as required
    }
};

std::sort(MyContainer.begin(), MyContainer.end() , mycomp());
```

Comment: @MehmetElliyasa Welcome to stackoverflow. In SO, when you think an answer is correct or useful, upvote it. Questions in SO are designed not only for the OP of the question, but for everybody who search a similar question and found this as his question answered. Upvotes reflects what are good answers and what not. Finally, if you think an answer solved your problem (As in this case), mark it as answer to your question (The green mark of the answer).

Comment: Your operator should be `const`. Some std library implementations may barf if you try to use a non-const one.

Comment: You can get the same effect as this custom comparison operator by defining operator< in Palet, then you can use std::sort with the default comparison.

Comment: @ZanLynx (although this already works) yours sounds also interesting... if it's just 1 or 2 lines... could you show me what you mean?

Comment: @Manu343726 i tried giving credit to the other good answers, but could not since it requires a minimum of 15 reputation. So i guess i have to wait and give them credit later.

Comment: @MehmetElliyasa: `bool operator<(const Palet& a, const Palet& b) { return p1.Aantal < p2.Aantal; }`

Answer (score 3):

Just use `std::sort`. I've used in programs which ran close to the 2GB process limit. "A million" elements perhaps sounds like a lot, but at 8 bytes that's still only 8 MB. It might even fit in cache.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use `std::sort` or similar, but I wouldn't be sorting huge elements directly in a `std::vector`. I would sort references to my big elements with the comparator. Each reference would be a simple container with a smart pointer to a big element.

You can also think of using `std::map` as a container which automatically gives you the sorted sequence.

Comment: -1 `std::sort` is dessigned not only to sort vectors. Is dessigned using the iterator pattern, that is, it sorts any interval defined by a initial iterator and a final iterator. If you defines a `begin()` and `end()` iterators in your awesome non-std::vector container, you could use it with `std::sort`.

Comment: Sorry I don't think you understood the idea. I didn't suggest to replace std::vector with a custom container. I suggested to wrap a reference to big element in a container and then sort the references.

Comment: If your big data class is moveable, that wrapping is not needed. Moving is cheap. If you have access to C++11 features, of course.